# Find error in this sentence

Tags: self-publishing, examples

Do not/ get panicked/ in emergencies/ no error.
I think,here 'panicked' is an adj, and hence 'no error' . If it is not so....then please suggest the right ans...

Comment: It might help if you gave some idea of context. A sign on the staircase of a hotel? (Not great, unless English is not the local language - see Boondoggle's answer) A sergeant berating a recruit after a badly performed exercise? (That fits nicely.) Is there a reason for the passive "get panicked" rather than an active "panic"?

Answer (score 2):

> Do not get panicked in emergencies.

is okay. But whether you want to write it that way is a second point.

Why not simply say:

> Do not panic in emergencies.

It says the same, and it's easier to read.

Comment: Is 'get panicky' better use than 'get panicked'??